# How do I configure nested subversion working copies in TeamCity?

Tags: svn, teamcity

We commit our projects to our local subversion server. Each of our projects has a folder called projectmaster. This folder is a nested svn working copy (with a different svn root as the projects it resides in) which contains common files we use in every project.

I managed to setup a teamcity (v.8.1) configuration to checkout and build one of our projects. The build fails, because I don't know how to tell teamcity to checkout the project and the nested projectmaster before building the project.

Any advice on how I could solve this problem?

Best regards,
Sascha

Comment: Could somebody please tell me, why my question was downvoted? If it the obove question is too stupid to ask, you could at least leave a comment...Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure why they downvoted it... I'd wager it has to do with using svn in a way many would describe as non-standard (nesting your repositories).  What language/tooling are you using other than team city?  You may benefit from building the libraries in their own build and consuming the artifacts in the applications that use them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I know that nesting svn is not the best idea, but that was neither my decision nor can I change that. So I try to make the best out of it. I would love to go for the library approach....I guess I will have to give up and forget about using a build server.

Comment: Is it nested working copies, or nested repositories? Both are bad ideas, but you've referred to one in the post title and the other in the body.

Comment: It's nested working copies. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. The error in my approach is that I checked out the projectmaster as a working copy on it's own.

Instead I have to use externals. That is I needed to define a svn:externals property on the root folder of my project working copy, that links the subfolder "projectmaster" to the external svn repository of my projectmaster.

As soon as that is done checking out or updating the project automatically checks out or updates the external.

That way teamcity will be able to build my project.

Sascha